# Seeing file names in TODO entries when using org-attach

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, attachment, org-attach

I use `org-attach` mostly to "move" files and store them under various TODO items. I find this an invaluable feature for keeping receipts and other important documents. The limitation of org-attachments is that there is no way of knowing **what** files are kept under the item just by looking at the entry. Org uses the keyword `:ATTACH:` to indicate that that entry has an attachment. One can also tell this by the fact that there is an `ID` generated under properties. It would however be a nice feature to be able to see at least the filenames one has under that entry, without having to actually call `org-attach`.

Comment: FWIW, I just do `C-c C-a F` (i.e. `org-attach-reveal-in-emacs`) to examine attachments. Having the filenames *in* the Org mode file would clutter it up too much for my taste. But you might want to submit a feature request to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html).

Comment: `org-attach-reveal-in-emacs` is my goto command. I understand the point about cluttering, but I still think it would be helpful to have the kind of information I suggest--as an option. Perhaps one could have a link to the file generated and placed into a note.

Comment: There is some resistance to add more options to Org mode (there are hundreds, not all of them documented and not all of them useful). But as I said, you can always submit a feature request (or, better, a patch to add the feature).

Comment: You should be able to cobble something together with `org-attach-dir` and `org-attach-file-list` (which see). The difficulty will be in keeping the attachment list in the Org mode file and the file list in the attachment directory in sync.

Comment: I see the problem with syncing. What I have done as a work around is to manually create a link to the file after I have attached it. This however tends to be quite tedious.

Comment: You can create links a bit more conveniently with `org-attach-complete-link`.

Comment: BTW, there is an `attachment` type link that use the aforementioned `org-attach-complete-link` so you don't have to write any code: `C-c C-l att TAB RET <select file with TAB completion> RET <description> RET` will do it.

Comment: That's an awesome tip that pretty much solves my problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Capturing and summarizing the comments as an answer.]

Although `org-attach` does not provide an automatic way to add the list of files in the attachment directory of a headline node to that node explicitly, it does provide some mechanisms which could be used to do so. There is no problem about getting the current list:

```el
(org-attach-file-list (org-attach-dir))
```

evaluated at a particular node, would return the list of files; inserting it in e.g. a drawer should not be too difficult. Keeping the two lists in sync is doable as well: one possibility is to add a function to `org-attach-after-change-hook` that recalculates the list and recreates the drawer from scratch. This is just an outline of course: an implementation would be nice.

One other possibility (which apparently meets the OP's requirements) is to manually create links to the entries. This too requires maintenance to keep things in sync, but assuming that links are mostly added and almost never deleted, the method will probably work well. It is based on the fact that Org mode supports [attachment links](https://orgmode.org/manual/External-Links.html#External-Links): one can then use the standard link creation mechanism of Org mode, `C-c C-l` (bound to `org-insert-link`) as follows:

```
C-c C-l att TAB RET <select attachment file with TAB completion> RET RET
```

The attachment link type uses `org-attach-complete-link` which provides tab completion for the files in the attachment directory of the node. The above invocation creates a link without a description, so the link looks like this:

```
[[attachment:filename]]
```

but a description can of course be provided if required. Note that the link does not contain the path of the attachment directory: the value of that is retrieved from the metadata stored in the node (the ID property that is added) in order to retrieve the file. That keeps the clutter in the Org mode file down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @NickD I did submit a feature request to the orgmode team and received a very helpful response from them. I believe that listing all the attached files used to be the  built-in, but was removed a few years ago. One can, however, still implement it for personal  use. The function and correspondence can be found at this public message URL:

https://orgmode.org/list/87sg70vsvy.fsf@localhost/